# Render method from helper via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In my `index.html.erb` of `transactions/views` I have:

```
<span id="davg_spending"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></span>
```

And in `transactions_helper.rb` I have a method:

```
def daily_average_spending(date)
  # Some logic
end
```

This method takes all user spendings (transactions) in `date.month` and count the average.
It takes a lot of time to count it, so it's better to render it after page loads via ajax.

So in `index.js.erb` I have:

```
$('#davg_spending').text('<%= j daily_average_spending(Date.today) %>');
```

But rails renders `index.html.erb` and I don't understand how to run `index.js.erb` after it.

My `index` method from `transactions_controller` is:

```
def index
  @transaction = current_user.transactions.new
  @transactions = current_user.transactions.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Peter,

your calling of daily_average_spending is done in the (format.)HTML rendering part.
you want to perform an ajax-request on the same url it seems, to invoke the .js rendering.

Comment: Ok, but don't understand how to perform it :) So I have an `index.js` file and I want to load it, after `index.html` loads. I know how to load `js` files with `remote: true` links, but how to do it without links?

Comment: in this case you`d add a javascriptsnipped like 
$('#davg_spending').load( "path/to/davg" ); - which will be triggered automaticaly. ensure its inside of document.ready